# Firefox Add-on-SDK page-mod Matchpattern/Wildcard Error

Tags: javascript, regex, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I need to exclude `http://forum.blockland.us/*sa=*` in my pagemod,

But there's always this error:

```
Error: There can be at most one '*' character in a wildcard.
```

Here's my main.js:

```
var pageMod = require("sdk/page-mod");

pageMod.PageMod({
  include: "http://forum.blockland.us/index.php?action=profile*",
  exclude: "http://forum.blockland.us/*sa=*",
  contentScript: 'document.body.innerHTML = ' +
                 ' "<h1>Page matches ruleset</h1>";'
});
```

It appears to be the `*sa=*` that causes the error. I'm not sure how to get around this.

If the answer is to have a regular expression or match pattern, I'd like to know how to include it in my main.js. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The [page-mod](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/page-mod#Globals) documentation indicates that the `include` and `exclude` attributes can be any of a string (with limited wildcards), a [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) ([regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)), or an array of these types.  You can get a more detailed description of [match-patterns on the MDN page describing them](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/util_match-pattern). Thus, to match what you want, you can use a regular expression in the `exclude` property instead of a string literal with wildcards:

```
var pageMod = require("sdk/page-mod");

pageMod.PageMod({
  include: "http://forum.blockland.us/index.php?action=profile*",
  exclude: /http:\/\/forum\.blockland\.us\/.*sa=.*/,
  contentScript: 'document.body.innerHTML = ' +
                 ' "<h1>Page matches ruleset</h1>";'
});
```

As you can see from the above, [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp), is just another type of [standard built-in object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects).  They can be entered as literals within your code.  You can also use the constructor:
`var myRegularExpression = new RegExp(pattern [, flags]);`

For example:

`var excludedPages = /http:\/\/forum\.blockland\.us\/.*sa=.*/;`
or
`var excludedPages = new RegExp ("http:\\/\\/forum\\.blockland\\.us\\/.*sa=.*");`

Note that when representing a string which you will use as input to the `new RegExp()` constructor a doubled backslash "\" is required if the string is being represented in your source code.  This is because when your code is being interpreted the conversion of the text as a [`String`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) literal uses a `\` to indicate that the next character is special.  Thus, a double backslash, `\\`, is required to indicate the actual backslash, `\`, should be in the `String`.  This would result in:

```
var pageMod = require("sdk/page-mod");
var excludedPages = /http:\/\/forum\.blockland\.us\/.*sa=.*/;

pageMod.PageMod({
  include: "http://forum.blockland.us/index.php?action=profile*",
  exclude: excludedPages,
  contentScript: 'document.body.innerHTML = ' +
                 ' "<h1>Page matches ruleset</h1>";'
});
```

Comment: I had to remove the `i` at the end of your regex for it to work. Otherwise, I got this error:   `Message: Error: A RegExp match pattern cannot be set to "ignoreCase" (i.e. //i).`

Comment: Yep, I should have read the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/page-mod) ([match-pattern](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/util_match-pattern)) a little bit closer.  None of the flags global (`g`), ignoreCase (`i`), and multiline (`m`) are permitted. Thanks for pointing that out. I have changed the code above to reflect this and updated the documentation at MDN to show RexExp as a permitted type (it wasn't in the explicit type declaration, but was mentioned in the text).